# React JS module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All the files inside src directory(using create-react-app). I can't seem to import search.js component into App.js file

src/App.js file code -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import SearchProfile from './search';

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
            </header>
            <p className="App-intro">
              To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

src/search.js file code -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class SearchProfile extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search--box">
         <form onSubmit={this.handleForm.bind(this)}>
           <label><input type="search" ref="username" placeholder="Type Username + Enter"/></label>
         </form>
      </div>
    )
  }

  handleForm(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    let username = this.refs.username.getDOMNode().value
    this.props.fetchProfile(username);
    this.refs.username.getDOMNode().value = '';
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error -

```
Failed to compile ./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './src/search'
```

I can't seem to find why it's not importing the module.

src/index.js file code -

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: If both file are in the same folder just use `import SearchProfile from './search';`

Comment: please check the code, I did but it's not working

Comment: Check your file name for search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your search.js has a couple of errors. You are not importing React as you do in app.js, you are exporting same class twice and you are importing App component. Try removing first and last line of file and import React, similar to how you do it App.js

Comment: Removed first and last line, imported react just like app.js still getting error

Comment: Try restarting build and make sure search.js is in same folder as App.js. I copied your code and it's fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xsd6td?file=src%2Fsearch.js

Comment: I had file name - "search,js" instead of "search.js" . Thank you for the help. The height of my stupidity :'(

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [MWE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kspajc?file=src%2Fapp.js) for your app.

There were a couple of errors:

- no import for `React` in your `App` component file
- you probably forgot to add the file name when importing `SearchProfile` (assuming it's in a directory "search" without "index.js" file)
- double default export for `SearchProfile`

I marked those in the code.

Comment: Edited the question, Please check now. All the files ( app.js / index.js / search.js ) in the src directory

Comment: That works too: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kspajc?file=src%2Fapp.js).

Comment: I had file name - "search,js" instead of "search.js" . Thank you for the help. The height of my stupidity :'(